# Can no longer pull from private git repository (Openshift Origin)

Tags: openshift-origin

I just upgraded to v1.1.1 and I am no longer able to access my private git repositories:

> builder.go:185] Error: build error: timeout while waiting for remote
>   repository
>   "https://username:password@enterprisewebservice.kilnhg.com/Code/EnterpriseWebService/Openshift-Docker-Builds/wildfly-jdk-8.git

Did something change?

This is my build config:

```
{
  "kind": "BuildConfig",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {
    "name": "wildfly-jdk-8-build",
    "creationTimestamp": null,
    "labels": {
      "name": "wildfly-jdk-8-build"
    }
  },
  "spec": {
    "triggers": [
      {
        "type": "github",
        "github": {
          "secret": "secret101"
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "generic",
        "generic": {
          "secret": "secret101"
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "imageChange",
        "imageChange": {}
      },
      {
        "type": "ConfigChange"
      }
    ],
    "source": {
      "type": "Git",
      "git": {
        "uri": "https://username:password@enterprisewebservice.kilnhg.com/Code/EnterpriseWebService/Openshift-Docker-Builds/wildfly-jdk-8.git"
      }
    },
    "strategy": {
      "type": "Docker",
      "dockerStrategy": {
        "from": {
          "kind": "ImageStreamTag",
          "name": "rhel:latest"
        }
      }
    },
    "output": {
      "to": {
        "kind": "ImageStreamTag",
        "name": "wildfly-jdk-8:latest"
      }
    },
    "resources": {}
  },
  "status": {
    "lastVersion": 0
  }
}
```

Comment: This is clearly tagged as being specific to Openshift Origin.  Stop downvoting it.  Stackoverflow is where they want us to ask questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rebooted my rhel 7 system and installed some updates and the issue seems to have cleared.﻿